# 2 runners on base, lead runner misses a base and both runs score, correct ruling?

Tags: rules, officiating, softball

Runner on first and second, ball is hit to outfield, both the runner on first and second score on the outfield hit. The runner who was on second, misses touching third base, and scores, followed by the runner who was on first...

appealed and the umpire called the runner out who missed 3rd base....

is this the correct call?

Comment: Can you edit your question to add which ruleset you are using?

Comment: How many outs are there?

Comment: @PhilipKendall - Baserunning rules are universal.  The pitcher would step on mound and then off and throw to third base to appeal.  Or in some cases would just hold the ball and tell umpire she wants to appeal.  The runner is called out for sure for missing the bag.  What the author needs to tell us is where the other runners went and how many outs there were because that is where it can get interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Tricky situation. Under baseball rules 7.08 (h) any runner is out when they pass another runner. However the runner never actually passes the other runner. So rule 7.10 (b) applies. In this case the first runner would be called out if a defensive player holding the ball were to tag the runner (who missed the bag) or third base.

Comment: Have you noticed this question is tagged "softball", not "baseball"?

Comment: @PhilipKendall Fortunately many of the same rules in baseball, especially those regarding baserunning and putouts are carried over into the game of softball. You are welcome to reference the rulebook of whatever governing body your softball league follows, but i would almost certainly guarantee that as far as baserunning goes the rules will be carried over from baseball. For example: see [International Softball Federation Playing Rules Committee](http://www.baseball-softball.de/wp-content/uploads/Softball-Rules-2014-2017-English.pdf) Rule 8 Sec 9. It's almost word for word the same as MLB

Answer (score 0):

If there are 2 outs when the appeal takes place, no runs score. If less than 2 outs, the trail runner would score.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Could you provide a reference to the rule book or other authority supporting this please?